# Pandas DF - Measure frequency, attached to appropriate rows and normalize by max(freq)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Assuming I create the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.random(20), 'B':np.random.random(20)})
df
Out[162]: 
           A         B
0   0.888651  0.380360
1   0.513343  0.605991
2   0.560978  0.076174
3   0.209426  0.498564
4   0.121748  0.771653
5   0.843299  0.279264
6   0.644060  0.725061
7   0.200187  0.349093
8   0.807808  0.657373
9   0.212760  0.384311
10  0.000725  0.023815
11  0.614540  0.534569
12  0.083690  0.228761
13  0.202334  0.266114
14  0.104520  0.757514
15  0.039944  0.014512
16  0.465300  0.164657
17  0.247370  0.894628
18  0.980589  0.833938
19  0.734673  0.745574
```

I then, want to:

1. Know the frequency of the 'B' columns which falls in the bins: `np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)`
2. Add that information as column 'freq'. So, for example, `row[0]` where `'B'` is 0.38 and is between `[0.35, 0.40)` is happening 2 times in the data frame. Therefor we will have `df['freq'][0] = 2`
3. Then, I want to have a new column called `'weights'` which will be, for each row, max(freq)/freq

I can solve 1 with something like: `df.groupby(pd.cut(df['B'], np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05))).count()` though there might be a more elegant way to do so

I fail to solve 2

And 3 is pretty straight forward.

Eventually, I only need the 'weights' column that is created by 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 1 using e.g. `np.digitize` and 2 using `transform()`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.random(20), 'B': np.random.random(20)})

bins = np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)
df["bins"] = np.digitize(df["B"], bins)
df["count"] = df.groupby("bins")["bins"].transform("count")
df["weight"] = df["count"].max()/df["count"]

df
Out[32]: 
           A         B  bins  count  weight
0   0.032735  0.948836    19      1     3.0
1   0.728310  0.671117    14      2     1.5
2   0.307804  0.328636     7      1     3.0
3   0.794719  0.257233     6      3     1.0
4   0.137138  0.480473    10      1     3.0
5   0.145847  0.754164    16      2     1.5
6   0.929552  0.187502     4      1     3.0
7   0.700309  0.655163    14      2     1.5
8   0.590829  0.561370    12      1     3.0
9   0.236366  0.814549    17      2     1.5
10  0.409573  0.444851     9      1     3.0
11  0.611366  0.842374    17      2     1.5
12  0.184661  0.725729    15      1     3.0
13  0.643751  0.299513     6      3     1.0
14  0.421400  0.294158     6      3     1.0
15  0.293585  0.112387     3      1     3.0
16  0.790870  0.609906    13      1     3.0
17  0.980155  0.757171    16      2     1.5
18  0.733151  0.393027     8      2     1.5
19  0.512966  0.398919     8      2     1.5
```

Comment: Thanks. Also works in a decent time: `Took 0.147000074387s`